# WordPress Adding tags to loop content

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am wrapping my head on wordpress loop at the moment, im trying to give tags to the respective content, so an H tag to the title, an p tag to the excerpt and so on...

The code i got so far is

```
<div id="<?php echo $page_id; ?>" class="container"><!-- begin container -->
<div id="postovi" style="display:none;">
<?php $custom_loop = new 
WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=Zanimljivosti&orderby=rand');
if (  $custom_loop->have_posts() ) :    echo '<ul>';    while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog') . get_the_excerpt();'</a></li>';      endwhile;   wp_reset_query();   echo '</ul>';endif;?>       </div>
```

any suggestions apreciated :)

Comment: sorry the code got a bit shredded, here is the full one <div id="<?php echo $page_id; ?>" class="container"><!-- begin container --> <div id="postovi" style="display:none;">
<?php $custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=Zanimljivosti&orderby=rand');if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : echo '<ul>'; while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();  echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog') . get_the_excerpt();'</a></li>';  endwhile; wp_reset_query(); echo '</ul>';endif;?>  </div>

Comment: sorry people i figured it out, ill leave the solution here in case someone might need it or someone wants to correct me :)

<?php $custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=Zanimljivosti&orderby=rand');if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : echo '<ul>'; while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();  
echo '<li><h2><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title(); echo '</h2>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); echo'<p>' . get_the_excerpt();'</p></a></li>';  endwhile; wp_reset_query(); echo '</ul>';endif;?>

Comment: Glad to hear that it's resolved. You could post your solution as an answer too here, so that it will help others facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

## So your solution is :

```
        <?php
        $custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=Zanimljivosti&orderby=rand');
        if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : 
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) :
        $custom_loop->the_post();    echo '<li><h2><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title();
        echo '</h2>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); 
        echo'<p>' . get_the_excerpt();'</p></a></li>'; 
        endwhile;   wp_reset_query();   
        echo '</ul>';endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: yes, sorry still getting used to the interface here :)